# Programmatically remounting usb hubs after boot ubuntu 10.04

Tags: usb, ubuntu-10.04, boot

I'm running ubuntu 10.04 and kernal 2.6.32-28-server.

There are 4 usb hubs connected to the server with 4 usb ports each. On boot only two or three of them get mounted. If I plug them in after boot then all are mounted just fine. On a different server with a more powerful power supply the usb hubs mount just fine on boot so this makes me think that there isn't enough power getting to the hubs on boot. I don't have the luxury of being able to replug them in every time so I have to figure out a way to get the usb hubs remounted programmatically sometime after boot.

So far I have tried other suggestions like.

Removing and reloading usb_storage:

```
sudo modprobe -w -r usb_storage; sudo modprobe usb_storage
```

I've also tried:

```
sudo modprobe -vr ehci_hcd
sudo modprobe -v ehci_hcd
```

But this just results in:

```
FATAL: Module ehci_hcd is builtin
```

Getting really desperate I copied some of the files in /sys/devices after successfully mounting by plugging the hubs in after boot into a separate folder. After rebooting the system I tried to copy those files back into /sys/devices but even as root I couldn't copy them.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so isn't suitable for Stack Overflow. Probably better over at [Super User](http://superuser.com/).